# Can't access S3 bucket from within Fargate container (Bad Request and unable to locate credentials)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-fargate

I created a private s3 bucket and a fargate cluster with a simple task that attempts to read from that bucket using `python 3` and `boto3`. I've tried this on 2 different docker images and on one I get a `ClientError` from boto saying `HeadObject Bad request (400)` and the other I get `NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`.

The only real different in the images is that the one saying bad request is being run normally and the other is being run manually by me via ssh to the task container. So I'm not sure why one image is saying "bad request" and the other "unable to locate credentials".

I have tried a couple different IAM policies, including (`terraform`) the following policies:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "access_s3" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["s3:ListBucket"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"]
  }

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:GetObjectVersion",
      "s3:GetObjectTagging",
      "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
    ]

    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"]
  }
}
```

Second try:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "access_s3" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["s3:*"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
  }
}
```

And the final one I tried was a build in policy:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "access_s3" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.ecstasks.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess"
}
```

the bucket definition is very simple:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
  acl    = "private"
  region = "${var.region}"
}
```

Code used to access s3 bucket:

```
try:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    tags = s3.head_object(Bucket='bucket_name', Key='filename')
    print(tags['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['etag'])
except ClientError:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

No matter what I do, I'm unable to use `boto3` to access AWS resources from within a `Fargate` container task. I'm able to access the same s3 bucket with `boto3` on an `EC2` instance without providing any kind of credentials and only using the IAM roles/policies. What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to access AWS resources in the same way from a Fargate container?

Forgot to mention that I am assigning the IAM roles to the task definition execution policy and task policy.

**UPDATE**: It turns out that the `unable to find credentials` error I was having is a red herring. The reason I could not get the credentials was because my direct ssh session did not have the `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` environment variable set.

AWS Fargate will inject an environment variable named `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` on your behalf which contains a url to what boto should use for grabbing API access credentials. So the `Bad request` error is the one I'm actually getting and need help resolving. I checked my environment variables inside the container and the `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` value is being set by Fargate.

Comment: I came across a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61250393/file-can-be-uploaded-to-s3-locally-but-cant-within-a-container-unable-to-locat . How can I set the enviornment variables inside the container?

Answer (score 28):

I struggled quite a bit with this issue and constantly having `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` wrongly set to `None`, until I added a custom task role **in addition** to my current **task execution role**.

**1)** The task execution role is responsible for having access to the container in ECR and giving access to run the task itself, while **2)** the task role is responsible for your docker container making API requests to other authorized AWS services.

1) For my task execution role I'm using `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` with the following JSON;

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2) I finally got rid of the `NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials` when I added a task role in addition to the task execution role, for instance, responsible of reading from a certain bucket;

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
           {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

In summary; make sure to both have a role for **1) executionRoleArn** for access to run the task and **2) taskRoleArn** for access to make API requests to authorized AWS services set in your task definition.

Comment: I was missing the `/*` in the resource arn of the s3 bucket :|

Comment: In my case, adding action ``s3:*`` causes the exact same error :/

Comment: It's not working for me. may I ask if you are running task in fargate mode or ec2 mode? I'm considering if I should attach the same policy to the ec2 instance where the container running on?

Comment: I'm running the task in fargate mode @SKSKSKSK

Comment: Looks like AWS wrote up a guide on this now: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-access-aws-services/

Comment: adding the task role in addition to the execution role solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To allow Amazon S3 read-only access for your container instance role

Open the IAM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/.

In the navigation pane, choose Roles.

Choose the IAM role to use for your container instances (this role is likely titled ecsInstanceRole). For more information, see Amazon ECS Container Instance IAM Role.

Under Managed Policies, choose Attach Policy.

On the Attach Policy page, for Filter, type S3 to narrow the policy results.

Select the box to the left of the AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess policy and choose Attach Policy.

Answer (score 1):

You should need an IAM Role to access from your ecs-task to your S3 bucket.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "AmazonS3ServiceForECSTask" {
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "bucket_policy" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_iam_role.AmazonS3ServiceForECSTask.arn]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:ListBucket",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.your_bucket_name}",
    ]
  }
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_iam_role.AmazonS3ServiceForECSTask.arn]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.your_bucket_name}/*",
    ]
  }
}
```

You should need add your IAM Role in **task_role_arn** of your task definition.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "_ecs_task_definition" {
  task_role_arn               = aws_iam_role.AmazonS3ServiceForECSTask.arn
  execution_role_arn          = aws_iam_role.ECS-TaskExecution.arn
  family                      = "${var.family}"
  network_mode                = var.network_mode[var.launch_type]
  requires_compatibilities    = var.requires_compatibilities
  cpu                         = var.task_cpu[terraform.workspace]
  memory                      = var.task_memory[terraform.workspace]
  container_definitions       = module.ecs-container-definition.json
}
```

[ECS Fargate task not applying role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078607/ecs-fargate-task-not-applying-role/61779327#61779327)

Answer (score 1):

After countless hours of digging this parameter finally solved the issue for me:

[auto_assign_public_ip = true](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#assign_public_ip) inside a network_configuration block on ecs **service**.

Turns out my tasks ran by these service didn't have IP assigned and thus no connection to outside world.

Comment: that was my issue, thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Boto3 has a credential lookup route: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html. When you use AWS provided images to create your EC2 instance, the instance pre-install the aws command and other AWS credential environmental variables. However, Fargate is only a container. You need to manually inject AWS credentials to the container. One quick solution is to add AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to the fargate container.

Comment: This isn't correct. The AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are not needed inside the container or even outside the container when using IAM roles. I've actually found more info on this and need to update my question. The Fargate instance injects an environment variable called `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` on your behalf behind the scenes which boto then uses to make AWS API calls in order to determine the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. So, those are not needed beforehand and are done automagically by AWS SDK and Fargate

Comment: Not really, if you want to isolate the permission by task, you should use the AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI. However, to convenience debug and update, isolating the permission by application makes more sense. One good way for me is to store the key pair of a given IAM in KMS and fetch them inside application.

Comment: But Kms also use credebtials to decrypt those keys