# Container is not able to call S3 in Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I'm not able to synchronize a log-folder to s3 inside a container.

I'm trying to get the following setup:

- Docker Container with installed awscli

  - there are logfiles and other files generated inside the container
- There is a cronjob, which calls the "aws s3 sync" command through a shell-script.

The synchronisation is not working properly and I'm not sure why not.

I tried the following, which worked just fine:

- provided access key/secret access key inside the docker container

  - this worked locally, with plain ECS and with fargate
  - but it's not recommended to use the access keys
- plain ECS without any keys (just the IAM role)

  - this worked too

I played a little with the configuration and read through the documentation.
The only hints I got are:

- Has it something to do with the network mode "awsvpc"? (which fargate has to use)
- Has it something to do with the "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" path variable?

  - I found a few hits there on the web, but I'm not sure if it's set or not. I'm not able to look inside the container in fargate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451041/cant-access-s3-bucket-from-within-fargate-container-bad-request-and-unable-to

Comment: Not a good idea to generate log files inside the container. Write the logs to the console of the container and send them using the `awslogs`

Comment: I know sending logs to cloudwatch is a better idea. But it's not always suitable for older projects. The logging to S3 should work at least...

Comment: I think I'm facing a similar problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sorry I never found a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

ECS Task Definition has two parameters related to defining IAM Role.

[executionRoleArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#execution_role_arn) - Provides access to the task or container to start running by performing needed actions such as pulling images from ECR, writing logs to Cloudwatch.

[taskRoleArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#task_role_arn) - Allows the Task to execute AWS API calls to interact with AWS resources such as S3, etc...

Comment: I created those roles, but it's not enough to get it working. I've read through the AWS documentation and have set everything as described. The taskRole should be enough...but it isnt... :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had a shell script which i used to call using entrypoint in the task definition. I had correctly set the Task Role with access to S3 however it did not work. So using the information provided here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=273767#898645
i added the first line in my shell script as

```
export AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
```

Still it did not work. Then i upgraded the AWS cli on the docker container to version 2 and it worked. So for me the real problem was that the docker image had an old CLI version.