# ECS Fargate task not applying role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS Fargate task running that has a role attached to it. This role has the S3FullAccess policy (and AssumeRole trusted partnership with ECS service).

However when trying to put an object into a bucket, I get Access Denied errors. I have tried booting an EC2 instance and attaching the same role and can put to the bucket without issue.

To me it seems like the role is not being attached to the task. Is there an important step I'm missing? I can't SSH into the instance as it's Fargate.

**UPDATE:**
I extracted the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables that are set and used them on my local machine. I am getting the Access Denied issues there too, implying (to me) that none of the polices I have set for that role are being applied to the task.

Anyone that can help with anything is appreciated!

**WORKAROUND:**
A simple workaround is to create an IAM User with programmatic access and set the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables in your task definition.

This works, but does not explain the underlying issue.

Comment: Which role have you defined in the task definition?

executionRoleArn - Provides access to the task to start container by performing necessary actions such as pulling images from ECR, writing logs to Cloudwatch.

taskRoleArn - Allows the container to make calls AWS resources (s3, dynamodb etc)

Comment: @Haran I've defined it as the taskRoleArn. I have executionRoleArn set with a role that has the correct permissions for pulling and starting the task.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem where I've extracted the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables and tried them locally and still getting access denied. Did you ever find a solution to this? (other than your workaround?)

Comment: same issue and no one answered my question in another page yet, good to see I'm not the only one facing this issue....

Comment: If you have made sure that you have set your Task Role and Execution Role correctly, this is most likely a problem on the SDK you are using. Most SDKs go through a default provider chain looking for envs, shared credentials file, ... ecs env. This depends on the programming language you are using. As an example for Go, visit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html#specifying-credentials

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just had a similar issue and I think it's probably due to your program being unable to access the role's credentials that are exposed by the Instance Metadata service.

Specifically, there's an environment variable called `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` and its value is what's needed by the AWS SDKs to use the task role. The ECS Container Agent sets it when your task starts, and it is exposed to the container's main process that has process ID 1. If your program isn't running as such, it might not being seeing the env var and so explaining the access denied error.

Depending on how your program is running, there'll be different ways to share the env var.

I had the issue inside ssh login shells (BTW you can ssh into Fargate tasks by running sshd) so in my Docker entrypoint script I inserted somewhere:

```sh
# To share the env var with login shells
echo "export AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" >> /root/.profile
```

In other cases it might work to add to your Docker entrypoint script:

```sh
# To export the env var for use by child processes
export AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
```

**References:**

- [IAM Roles for Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) - docs explaining the env var relating to the role
- [AWS Forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=273767#898645) - where someone explains these workarounds in greater detail

Answer (score 2):

**Amazon ECS container credentials**– loaded from the Amazon ECS if the environment variable AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI is set.

You define the [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-iam-roles.html) to use in your **[task definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_TaskDefinition.html)**, or you can use a **taskRoleArn** override when running a task manually with the RunTask API operation. The Amazon ECS agent receives a payload message for starting the task with additional fields that contain the role credentials. The Amazon ECS agent sets a unique task credential ID as an identification token and updates its internal credential cache so that the identification token for the task points to the role credentials that are received in the payload. The Amazon ECS agent populates the AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment variable in the Env object (available with the docker inspect container_id command) for all containers that belong to this task with the following relative URI: /credential_provider_version/credentials?id=task_credential_id.

Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "AmazonS3ServiceForECSTask" {
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "bucket_policy" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_iam_role.AmazonS3ServiceForECSTask.arn]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}",
    ]
  }
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_iam_role.AmazonS3ServiceForECSTask.arn]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:PutObjectAcl",
      "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
      "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}/*",
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my_app_ecs_task_definition" {
  task_role_arn               = aws_iam_role.AmazonS3ServiceForECSTask.arn
  execution_role_arn          = aws_iam_role.ECS-TaskExecution.arn
  family                      = "${var.family}"
  network_mode                = var.network_mode[var.launch_type]
  requires_compatibilities    = var.requires_compatibilities
  cpu                         = var.task_cpu[terraform.workspace]
  memory                      = var.task_memory[terraform.workspace]
  container_definitions       = module.ecs-container-definition.json
}
```