# AWS Batch container cannot access S3 via aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-batch

I'm trying to run an AWS Batch job, but it is failing when calling `aws-cli` to copy data from s3 into the container. The error message is as follows:

```
fatal error: Unable to locate credentials
```

My job definition has an execution role with two managed policies: `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy`. The container image is built from the default `ubuntu:22.04` image, and has an entry point file similar to:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

aws s3 cp ...
```

I've also been reading the following question: [ECS Fargate task not applying role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078607/ecs-fargate-task-not-applying-role), which states that the container should have a variable `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`, but I don't have that. I've added a `declare -x` in my entry point, and this is its output when I execute the Batch job:

```
declare -x AWS_BATCH_CE_NAME="MyCluster"
declare -x AWS_BATCH_JOB_ATTEMPT="1"
declare -x AWS_BATCH_JOB_ID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
declare -x AWS_BATCH_JQ_NAME="MyQueue"
declare -x AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-2"
declare -x AWS_EXECUTION_ENV="AWS_ECS_FARGATE"
declare -x AWS_REGION="us-west-2"
declare -x DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
declare -x ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI="http://111.111.111.1/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
declare -x ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4="http://111.111.111.1/v4/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
declare -x HOME="/root"
declare -x HOSTNAME="ip-111-11-1-111.us-west-2.compute.internal"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
declare -x PWD="/"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
```

Also, when setting up a Fargate cluster, I can see that a Task Definition has a "Task Role" in addition to the execution role. My understanding is that the "Task Role" is a role defined *inside* the container, while the execution role is defined to setup the container. In Batch, there is no such "Task Role". So, my question is, how can I authorize my container to access my AWS resources with `aws-cli` inside the container?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured out how to pass permissions to the container. The Job Definition has a "Job Role" which is passed directly to the ECS Task Role, but that configuration option isn't available in the AWS Console. One must register the Job Definition via API or CLI, in the `--container-properties` parameter:

```sh
aws batch register-job-definition --container-properties '{"jobRoleArn": "...","executionRoleArn": "..."}' ...
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, you put me on the right way with the "jobRoleArn" tip! It finally works! Now this option is also available in the AWS Console under Job Configuration => Job Configuration Role.

Comment: Thanks! This took 2 hours before reading this. You must set the `Job role ARN`. Do not confuse this with the `Execution role ARN`